# how to pull the fields from custom object in email template

Tags: email

I want to pull the fields form other custom object to email template.how could this be achieved???

i have tried using the merge fields but not achieved.
formula field is also not possible as no relationship is there for that fields

Answer (score 1):

You can create a visualforce email template and after that you can add a visualforce component into that email template. Your visualforce email template will look like this

Here is one example from doc

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_email_templates_with_apex.htm

I hope it will help you.

Comment: i want to use only standard template........how to do

Comment: we don't have that functionality in standard html template. vf template type is the only option alternative approach would be to create new fields on your object and write a trigger on your custom object to fill those fields.